# JavaFX Maven failed to execute goal

Tags: java, maven, javafx

I recentely created my JavaFX Maven Project with IntelliJ and JDK-11. But If I run mvn javafx:run I get this error:

> Failed to execute goal org.openjfx:javafx-maven-plugin:0.0.1:run
> (default-cli) on project RaspberryShell: Error

I really searched the whole internet and found nothing. Any ideas?

This is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>de.Jan.Raspberry.Shell</groupId>
    <artifactId>RaspberryShell</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.55</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>14</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>14</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.6</executable>
                    <mainClass>de.Jan.Raspberry.Shell.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Edit:
This is the full error:

```
[INFO] 
[INFO] ---------------< de.Jan.Raspberry.Shell:RaspberryShell >----------------
[INFO] Building RaspberryShell 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- javafx-maven-plugin:0.0.1:run (default-cli) @ RaspberryShell ---
[WARNING] Required filename-based automodules detected. Please don't publish this project to a public artifact repository!
[ERROR] Command execution failed.
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.6" (in directory "C:\Users\jan\Desktop\Programmieren\Java\Other\RaspberryShell\RaspberryShell\RaspberryShell"): CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start (ProcessBuilder.java:1128)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start (ProcessBuilder.java:1071)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec (Runtime.java:589)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.launcher.Java13CommandLauncher.exec (Java13CommandLauncher.java:61)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.launch (DefaultExecutor.java:279)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal (DefaultExecutor.java:336)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute (DefaultExecutor.java:166)
    at org.openjfx.JavaFXRunMojo.executeCommandLine (JavaFXRunMojo.java:525)
    at org.openjfx.JavaFXRunMojo.executeCommandLine (JavaFXRunMojo.java:487)
    at org.openjfx.JavaFXRunMojo.execute (JavaFXRunMojo.java:168)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:47)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create (Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init> (ProcessImpl.java:478)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start (ProcessImpl.java:154)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start (ProcessBuilder.java:1107)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start (ProcessBuilder.java:1071)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec (Runtime.java:589)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.launcher.Java13CommandLauncher.exec (Java13CommandLauncher.java:61)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.launch (DefaultExecutor.java:279)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal (DefaultExecutor.java:336)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute (DefaultExecutor.java:166)
    at org.openjfx.JavaFXRunMojo.executeCommandLine (JavaFXRunMojo.java:525)
    at org.openjfx.JavaFXRunMojo.executeCommandLine (JavaFXRunMojo.java:487)
    at org.openjfx.JavaFXRunMojo.execute (JavaFXRunMojo.java:168)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:47)
```

Comment: Can you provide longer log of maven errors?

Comment: Edited the message

Comment: See the answer.

Comment: Your `<executable>...</executable>` points to the JDK directory but not the executable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's check your log together. You're told, that:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.6" (in directory "C:\Users\jan\Desktop\Programmieren\Java\Other\RaspberryShell\RaspberryShell\RaspberryShell"): CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied
```

which then causes:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied
```

`error=5` usually means, that you either:

1. have a wrong path to the executable file; (by the way, is *"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.6"* path to the executable? I don't think so)
2. have no permission to read(run) that file.

You have to make sure your path to the executable file is correct, and that you have an appropriate (required) access to it.